# Rails 4: Error on collection through association in (TestCase) controller index action test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, functional-testing, fixtures

**polls_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @polls = current_user.polls
  end
```

Above works fine for my user (current_user) has_many polls association. I thought I could replicate this in tests by setting appropriate fixtures.

**polls_controller_test.rb**

```
  setup do
    @current_user = users(:bob)
    @poll = @current_user.polls.build(title: "Poll")
  end

  test "should get index" do
    @polls = @current_user.polls
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:polls)
  end
```

**polls.yml**

```
one:
  title: Poll-1
  user: bob

two:
  title: Poll-2
  user: bob
```

**users.yml**

```
bob:
  name: Bob Example
  email: bob@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

However, running the test returns

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `polls' for nil:NilClass
```

Can I not do this? (Apparently not this way.) Why is @current_user nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. As always, was not due to some esoteric bug or syntax requirement, but rather that I did not specify session[:user_id] = @current_user.id in the test setup, which is referenced by my current_user helper method. Therefore, test framework was seeing current_user as nil. Cheers.